# greping two regex at the same time

Tags: regex, scripting, grep

How to use grep to search for two regex at the same time. Say, I am looking for "My name is" and "my bank account " in a text like:

```
My name is Mike. I'm 16 years old.
I have no clue how to solve my grep problem,but
if I manage to solve it, then I'll transfer 
you some money from my bank account.
```

I'd like grep to return:

My name is
my bank account

Is it possible to do it with just one grep call or should I write a script to do that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about a trailing newline, simply use `grep`:

```
< file.txt grep -o "My name is\|my bank account" | tr '\n' ' '
```

If you would prefer a trailing newline, use `awk`:

```
awk -v RS="My name is|my bank account" 'RT != "" { printf "%s ", RT } END { printf "\n" }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

pipe.  `grep expr1 file | grep expr2`

for or - `egrep '(expr1|expr2)' file`

Comment: this will return only lines that contain both expr1 *and* expr2.  The poster wants *or* ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're after. The result you give doesn't seem to fit with anything grep can/will do. In particular, grep is line oriented, so if it finds a match in a line, it includes that entire line in the output. Assuming that's what you really want, you can just `or` the two patterns together:

```
grep ("My name is" | "my bank account")
```

Given the input above, this should produce:

```
My name is Mike. I'm 16 years old.
you some money from my bank account.
```

Alternatively, since you haven't included any meta-characters in your patterns, you could use fgrep (or grep -F) and put your patterns in a file, one per line. For two patterns this probably doesn't make a big difference, but if you want to look for lots of patterns, it'll probably be quite a bit faster (it uses the Aho-Corasick string search to search for all the patterns at once instead of searching for them one at a time).

The other possibility would be that you're looking for a single line that includes both `my name is` and `my bank account`. That's what @djechlin's answer would do. From the input above, that would produce *no* output, so I doubt it's what you want, but if it is, his answer is fairly reasonable. An alternative would be a pattern like `("My name is.*my bank account" | "my bank account.*My name is")`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. I used sed. You can replace S1 and S2 with whatever you want

```
sed '/S1/{ s:.*:S1:;H};/S2/{ s:.*:S2:;H};${x;s:\n: :g;p};d'
```

Sed is much more complex than grep, and in this case I used it to simulate grep's behaviour that you wish.